# taphold it will not work with input type radio

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-mobile

i use Jquery Mobile

here is my code below but it will not work. as I want when I tap on a radio button to make me the action live. Any Idea why does not work?

```
$('#lbtn').append("<input name='opt1' class='rd_btn' checked type='radio' value="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+"    id="+results.rows.item(i).IdRubrique+" />");


$('.rd_btn').live('taphold', function() 
          {
            var sel_id_rub = $('input[name=opt1]:checked').attr('id');//ID of Rubrique
            window.localStorage.setItem("id_rub", sel_id_rub);       //Id Rubrique
            liste_Phrase();
          }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above example is based on your code. When the taphold event is fired then the corresponding id of the input element is shown inside an alert box.

The idea is to attach the taphold event handler on the created element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <head> 
        <title>Taphold Example</title> 
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var i = 0;
            $(document).on('click', '#add', function(e){
                i++;
                var labeledRadio = $(["<label><input name=\"opt1\" class=\"rd_btn\" checked type=\"radio\" id=myId_",i," value=myval_",i," id=myId_",i,">Label_",i,"</input></label>"].join("")).on('taphold', function() {  alert($(this).parent().children("input[type=radio]").attr('id')); });
                $('#lbtn').append(labeledRadio).trigger('create');
            });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <!-- /page -->
        <div data-role="page">
            <!-- /header -->
            <div data-role="header" data-theme="b">
                <h1>Taphold test</h1>
            </div>
            <!-- /content -->
            <div data-role="content">
                <input type="button" id="add" value="Add Inputs"/>        
                <div id="lbtn"></div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps.